# Timed Out at Control Panel Login as Super Admin

Tags: control-panel, login, super-admin

I have a site that I have running on a company server that is an internal server. It does not allow requests from outside to come in. The entire site works fine on my local computer and on a server that is external.

On my internal server I am getting these errors in the error log

`[warn]  mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 61 seconds`

`[error]  Premature end of script headers: admin.php`

So my thought is that it is something with it calling out and waiting on a response. I have disabled the Auto check for update in the control panel. And that allowed it to work for a little while. But now I am not able to login as a Super Admin. I am able to login as any other type of member including one that is a copy of the Super Admin profile.

I am running EE 2.7.3

Does anyone have any help for me?

Thanks

Comment: I have copied the site over to a subdirectory on the domain and once I did that I was able to login as a Super Admin. This has got me stumped.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried cranking up max_execution_time? Try 300 Various ways to do it - some cPanel versions let you configure it along with php version or you could use a php.ini file

Comment: I have. It will just go to that time and then time out.